# Get coordinates of clicked point on screen in model space

Tags: opengl, camera, coordinates, qt

There is a 2D object located in the coordinate range -1 to 1. In world space, it is also located in these coordinates, but with a shift along the z axis.
The actual initialization of the model, view and projection matrices:

```
m_model.setToIdentity();
m_view.setToIdentity();
m_projection.setToIdentity();

m_model.translate({0.0, 0.0, -3.0});
m_projection.perspective(38.0, 1.0 * 640 / 480, 0.1, 100.0);
```

When I click on the rightmost edge of my circle on the screen, I want to get its coordinate, x = 1.0, since r = 1.0.

I have tried several different methods that give the same result, not suitable for me.

1)

```
    QMatrix4x4 mat = m_view * m_projection * m_model;
    QMatrix4x4 invMat = mat.inverted();
    //NDC x and y
    float pt_x = (p.x()/640.0)*2.0f - 1.0f; 
    float pt_y = -(p.y()/480.0)*2.0f + 1.0f;

    QVector4D nearPlane(pt_x,pt_y, -1.0, 1.0);
    QVector4D farPlane(pt_x, pt_y, 1.0, 1.0);
    QVector4D nearRes = invMat * nearPlane;
    QVector4D farRes = invMat * farPlane;
    nearRes /= nearRes.w();
    farRes /= farRes.w();
    QVector3D direc = QVector3D(farRes - nearRes);
    direc.normalize();
```

2. 

```
    QVector3D screenPos(p.x(),p.y(),1.0f);
    QVector3D vecUnproj = screenPos.unproject(m_view(),m_projection(),QRect(0,0, 640, 480));
    vecUnproj.normalize();
```

Output:

```
direc = QVector3D(0.314588, 0, -0.949228)
vecUnproj = QVector3D(0.314589, 0, -0.949228)
```

As a result, the resulting vector has x = 0.31, and I expected 1.0. And even clicking on the edge of the window gives me a value of about 0.45. I understand that it looks like I am not taking something into account in the transformation or am not doing some other operation.

[image: Window with radar grid]